# Read comma separated values from a text file using php

Tags: php, file

I have a text file which consists of content that is comma separated.

Let my file be `test.txt`. The content is:

```
text1, text2, text3
```

I want to read this file and assign these three values into 3 variables.

I have checked `readfile(filename,include_path,context)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
$textCnt  = "text.txt";
$contents = file_get_contents($textCnt);
$arrfields = explode(',', $contents);

echo $arrfields[0]; 
echo $arrfields[1]; 
echo $arrfields[2];
```

Or, in a loop:

```
foreach($arrfields as $field) {
    echo $field;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy it helped

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) where you don't need to explode the values.

If your csv file uses a different delimiter, simply pass it as a parameter to `fgetcsv`

Example

```
$h = fopen("csv.csv", "r");

while (($line = fgetcsv($h)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r($line);
}

fclose($h);
```