# Explode is returning an empty array

Tags: php

```
$allMessages = array();
if ($file = fopen("messages.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $line = fgets($file);
        $parts = explode(", ", $text);
        array_push($allMessages, $parts);
    }
    fclose($file);
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($allMessages);
echo '</pre>';
```

i did this but it returned an empty string
idk what happened

##returned
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[0] =>
)

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
    )
```

)
btw the file consist of
`names, message`
(it is separated by comma)
it splits it by the `explode` function but it returned empty string
pls help meh

Comment: `$text` is __defined nowhere__

Comment: Well I was going to say  let's turn IDK into I Do Know by using a var_dump($line) after you assign it in the while loop but then saw the next line where you are using $text and I Dont Know where that is assigned?  It looks like a little typo there.

Comment: possible duplicate of : [Read comma separated values from a text file using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32962359/read-comma-separated-values-from-a-text-file-using-php)

Comment: But do you know 100% that each line is structured as xxxxx, yyyyyy with a comma space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me that you want to do `$parts = explode(", ", $line);` because `$text` is not defined.